# Excel - Count the number times values in array 1 appear in array 2

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I've only just started using arrays (as in yesterday) and have tried ambitiously to use them in a work spreadsheet but am having issues. Details are as follows:

I have a table of data with column R containing a list of room numbers (where each room number can appear more than once and each instance needs to be counted.). I want to then count how many of those room numbers are also in my list in column Z(particular room type).

I can do this by checking each room number individually but was wondering if it was possible to do with this by checking the entire array at once.

Comment: "those room numbers are also in my list in column Z(particular room type)" Does column Z contain a room number or a room type?

Comment: Column Z contains room numbers that belong to a certain room type

Comment: So do we need to check room types in another column to do this calculation? Or can we just compare R and Z?

Comment: Just compare R and Z. I have other room types in columns AA,AB,AC each with the corresponding room numbers and will check those seperately

Comment: Have you tried countif()?

Comment: Yes but it didn't give me the result I hoped for when doing it as an array {=COUNTIF(R2:R1709,Z2:Z199)}

Comment: @ScottCraner Due to duplication concerns in the question, I think the task is messier than just an obvious countif() usage.

Comment: Use `=Sumproduct(COUNTIF(R2:R1709,Z2:Z199))`

Comment: Does my answer accomplish what you want? Give you the answer you expect?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @ScottCraner I did, best so far but I'm getting a total of 1682 results where I should be getting 1708, likely to be room number listings. Will investigate and get back to you.

Comment: I would bet that there are spelling/typos/extra spaces in some of your data, that is making it so it is not being picked up.

Comment: @Scott Data was fine, I was the problem, left out a room number in one of the types. Thanks Scott for your answer. Haven't used sumproduct before,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of @Scott Craner who suggested:

=Sumproduct(COUNTIF(R2:R1709,Z2:Z199))

Thanks also to @Mark Balhoff as well.

Answer (score 0):

I mocked up an array formula to accomplish the task. Probably not the best implementation but it was quick. As always you need to enter an array formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Note that I assumed each column had 15 rows and started in row 1.

**Count Duplicates Independently**

```
=SUM(1*NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(R1:R15,$Z$1:$Z$15,0))))
```

**Count Duplicates As One**

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(R1:R15,R1:R15),0)*NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(R1:R15,$Z$1:$Z$15,0))))
```

The formula breaks down like so...

```
IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(R1:R15,R1:R15),0)
```

Returns 1/(# of occurrences of a given cell value in all of column R). This allows us to sum up 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 if a room number is in column R three times (so we only count it once).

```
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(R1:R15,$Z$1:$Z$15,0)))
```

Returns TRUE if the given column R cell value occurs in column Z and FALSE otherwise. When we multiply this time the first part, TRUE becomes 1 and FALSE becomes 0.

```
=SUM(...)
```

Sum up all the intermediate products.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think my question could have been better explained as I also need to count the duplicates (I added the fact that there were duplicate values incase this altered the required formula). My apologies. I will update the OP. I appreciate the breakdown

Comment: @pita Ok well then that simplifies things. Let me tweak my answer.

Comment: @pita There's the quick fix to count each duplicate separately. Just replaces the `IFERROR(...)` with `1`.

Comment: Your NOT(ISERROR()) could be replaced with ISNUMBER().  It will ignore all the errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes it could. I just wrote whatever required the least thought (tired; recovering from illness). I don't know whether either method has an advantage here. If there is a performance difference, I would expect it to be negligible.

Comment: It is the same just less typing. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner Well you beat me badly in this round of the seemingly every question SO game of "figure out what the OP actually wants" (despite my questions in comments to OP). ;)

Comment: I like to wait and see when the OP is responsive. Then swoop in with the answer.:)